# Is it possible to have an arbitrary number of type arguments for an abstract method?

Tags: c#, inheritance, types, abstract-class, abstraction

I have an abstract class, and I want to let the derived class define not only the value type, but let them define how many value types they have. Then I want to require them to have getters/setters for each type:

```
public abstract class A<T1, T2, ..., TN>
{
    // Getters
    public abstract T1 GetValue();
    public abstract T2 GetValue();
    ...
    public abstract TN GetValue();
    // Setters
    public abstract void SetValue(T1 newVal);
    public abstract void SetValue(T2 newVal);
    ...
    public abstract void SetValue(TN newVal);
}
```

Then the classes that derive from A can have as many values as they want, as long as they provide access to them. Is this possible in c#? Or something similar to it?

Comment: I don't think so, otherwise Microsoft would have implemented `Tuple` this way. Instead there is `Tuple<T1>`, `Tuple<T1, T2>`, `Tuple<T1, T2, T3>` and so forth. The same thing applies for `Action` and `Func`.

Answer (score 5):

No. They must be explicitly defined because the compiler has to figure out what to do with the types to build into the assembly.

You could obtain a similar effect via a code generator.